# Как отключить предупреждения о неиспользуемых сущностях в MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, warning

В `gcc` можно одним флагом отключить предупреждения о неиспользованных сущностях — `Wno-unused`. Как сделать это в `msvc` (не меняя исходный код)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключение предупреждения: `/wdXXXX` - где вместо XXXX - вставить номер предупреждения. [см.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170)

В данном случае предупреждение [о неиспользуемых аргументах](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4100?view=msvc-170): `/wd4100`

`/wd4100` - 'identifier': unreferenced formal parameter
`/wd4101` - 'identifier': unreferenced local variable
`/wd4102` - 'label':
unreferenced label

Можно, также, поменять уровень предупреждений `/w3`.  (Эти три предупреждения появляются только на 4-м уровне.) Но это может отключить больше предупреждений чем вы хотите.

Comment: Через `/wdXXXX` получилось отключить 1 `XXXX` предупреждение. `Wno-unused` отключает сразу несколько. В `msvc` последнее невозможно?

Comment: Только `/wd4100`, через `w` в нижнем регистре.